# programmatically adding custom animation to fragment using objectAnimator

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I currently add custom animation to my fragments using the following code.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in, R.animator.slide_in, R.animator.slide_out, R.animator.slide_out );
ft.add(R.id.container, new Doze1Fragment());
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Now I'm playing around with adding a few different fragments on top of each other in a span of 3 to 5 seconds and then pop all of them out of the back stack to get a "fanning" animation out of all fragments. In order to do so I either add a delay in between each popBackStack() call (I think this is a horrible solution), or make a custom XML animator resource for each fragment. I was wondering if anyone has any idea of how to do this programmatically right before calling ft.add(R.id.container, new Doze1Fragment()). I know that normally I could use the following code to animate a view and I was looking for something similar

```
ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(R.id.container, "x", 0, 1000f);
oa.setDuration(300);
oa.start();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to stack all the fragment and then pop out together. Is this what you meant ?

Comment: Yeah. Each fragment enters from the side of the screen and gets added to the top of the previous one. Then I would prefer to pop them all together and hoping that they each have a custom animation with slightly different "Duration" so it would get a "fanning effect" as they exit the screen.